# Trouble pushing items to a cart when user adds to order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a simple restaurant menu app. When a user selects "add to order" i want to push that content into an array of objects aka a cart. I can read the id, name, price, etc from the item being added, but When i push to the array, it is not saving the next time around when the user clicks add to order. I've tried various ways including spread operators to keep saving the array. But i can't figure this out. Can anyone help?

```
  const addToOrder = (obj) => {


  console.log(obj.id);
  console.log(obj.name);
  console.log(obj.price);

  let orderCart = [];

  orderCart.push(obj); // i think i need to create some kind of loop here to push and save the array, but i could be wrong

  let orderCartSaved = orderCart;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not re-initialize `orderCart` within `addToOrder()`.

Make `orderCart` as a class variable, or have it outside `addToOrder()`.

```
const orderCart = [];

const addToOrder = (obj) => {

    console.log(obj.id);
    console.log(obj.name);
    console.log(obj.price);

    orderCart.push(obj);
}
```